# WYSIWYG CSS-editing?

Tags: css, wysiwyg

Are there any apps or browser extensions that provide rudimentary CSS-editing via WYSIWYG?

For example I would like the tool to let me resize any box DIV on a page by selecting it and then dragging the sizing controls.

Comment: IMO no wysiwyg can compare to making the edits in a text editor then refreshing it in a browser.

Comment: This would be the point of designing in Photoshop or another design application first then coding to match the design. For the record Dreamweaver lets you do this stuff but it creates absolutely atrocious code. There is also a Photoshop plugin that will convert layers into CSS3 code but I forget it's name.

Comment: @RickCalder: This isn't the one you're thinking of... but what your comment reminds me of is Adobe Muse: http://www.adobe.com/products/muse.html

Answer (score 2):

You should really try and use the inspector that is built into your web browser (preferably Chrome in my opinion) or perhaps [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox.  These changes you make will be erased on refresh, but it will allow you for quick CSS prototyping.

However, I will say that what your looking for probably isn't as good of an idea as just editing text in a text editor and refreshing your changes over multiple browsers.  I say multiple browsers because it's always best to write code that works for as many platforms and as many browsers as reasonable for the project.  Stay away from in-browser WYSIWYG editors for code and stick to an IDE like Dreamweaver, TextMate, Coda, and the like.